# Login with facebook unable to work on device which have facebooklite app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

i am using facebook sdk 4.14 it propely work on device which dosent have Facebooklite app

```
               FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
            final  Dialog dlg = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dlg.setContentView(R.layout.fblogindilog);
            TextView continuew=(TextView)dlg.findViewById(R.id.cont);
            TextView fbusername=(TextView)dlg.findViewById(R.id.usname);
            lgnfb = (LoginButton) dlg.findViewById(R.id.fblogin);
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if (accessToken == null) {

            dlg.show();


                lgnfb.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                lgnfb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                GetNameId(object);




                            }
                        });
                        Bundle parameters=new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                        dlg.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sujab.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login cancled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unable to connect with facebook your internet is slow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                continuew.setText("Continue with same account");
                SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("USERINFO",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String namefb=sp.getString("Name"," ");
                fbusername.setText("Welcome! "+namefb);
                dlg.show();

                continuew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sujab.class);
                            startActivity(intent);




                    }
                });
                lgnfb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are sucessfuly logout please login for sujab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dlg.dismiss();


                    }
                });
```

and

```
             private void GetNameId(JSONObject object) {
    try {
     name=object.getString("name");
        userid=object.getString("id");
        Log.d("Name::",name);
        Log.d("id::",userid);
      sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("USERINFO",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed=sharedPreferences.edit();
        ed.putString("Name",name);
        ed.putString("Id",userid);
        ed.clear();
        ed.commit();




    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

But when i instal this apk on device which has Facebooklite app it directly open facebooklite what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following line after initializing callbackManager :

```
lgnfb.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```